# IIS Web Application can't be accessed remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, iis-8

I have created a web application in Asp.Net . I deployed it on an IIS Server and the web app works fine on my machine but when i try to access it on another computer it dosen't work.Internal Server Error occurred is the message. Do i need to convert this web application as website ? Is there any way to make a web application deployed on IIS 8 to be accessible on another machine?

Comment: check out your iis log to see what the exception is

Comment: @Steve nothing in log files...just entries..do i need to enable anything to see exception logs